# I can't connect my database table to my website in order to register and sign in

Tags: php, mysql

My website fully functions on localhost but now that I put it on web hosting the account doesn't work, I cannot register or login. I know that it works because it previously did so there is a problem with the connection to the user table in my database. The other table with products is successfully connected. How do I fix this problem in my code?

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');
$conn = connect();

$email  = $_POST['Email'];
$pass   = $_POST['Password'];
$type   = $_POST['type'];

if($type == "signup"){
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email like ?");
    $sql->bind_param('s', $email);

    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "This email is already in use"; 
    }
    else{
        /*Part 1*/
        $sqlInsert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`UID`, `Email`, `Password`, `FName`, `LName`, `Country`, `City`, `Address`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, '', '', '', '', '');");
        $sqlInsert->bind_param('ss', $email, $pass);

        $sqlInsert->execute();

        echo "Success!";
    }
}
else if($type == "login"){
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email like ?");
    $sql->bind_param('s', $email);

    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if($row["Password"] == $pass){
                // Log in
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login_user'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['account_id'] = $row["UID"];
                echo "Success!";
            }
            else{
                echo "Wrong credentials!";
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Wrong credentials!";
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I think the problem may be here

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';

    function connect() {
        $conn = new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        return $conn;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you update the SERVER_NAME, USER, PASSWORD, and DB_NAME values to match you new server? If so, are you sure the user table exists in the same DB as products?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: whats that mysqli()? is it https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code please fill below fields
my_user: default 'root' 
my_password: default ''
my_db: your database name

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

function connect()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_db");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    return $con;
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't make a difference, I still can't register or connect